# How to Update a datetime field with current date time in VF page?

Tags: visualforce, datetime, field-update

I need to update a datetime field with current date time in VF page using JavaScript.Currently my code is like this :

```
        var newRecords = [];
        var a = new sforce.SObject("myObj__c");
        a.id ="{!myObj.Id}";
        var today = new Date();
        a.Last_Time_Executed__c = sforce.internal.dateTimeToString(today);
        newRecords.push(a);
        result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
```

But it shows this error:

> {faultcode:'soapenv:Client',
>   faultstring:''2013-11-27T13:04:46.539+05.5:30' is not a valid value
>   for the type xsd:dateTime', }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked:

```
        var newRecords = [];
        var a = new sforce.SObject("MyObj__c");
        a.id ="{!SOQL_Report__c.Id}";
        a.Last_Time_Executed__c = new Date().toISOString();
        newRecords.push(a);
        result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
```